# Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown - different behavior for CLI vs webpack-eslint-plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, eslint

I’m running into this error:

```
Error: ../library/.eslintrc.js » ../app/.eslintrc.js » eslint-config-react-app/jest#overrides[0]:
    Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown

    at /home/project/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/shared/config-validator.js:175:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigValidator.validateEnvironment (/home/project/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/shared/config-validator.js:169:34)
    at ConfigValidator.validateConfigArray (/home/project/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/shared/config-validator.js:319:18)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (/home/project/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/cascading-config-array-factory.js:493:23)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (/home/project/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/cascading-config-array-factory.js:299:21)
    at FileEnumerator._iterateFilesRecursive (/home/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/file-enumerator.js:481:49)
    at _iterateFilesRecursive.next (<anonymous>)
    at FileEnumerator.iterateFiles (/home/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/file-enumerator.js:296:49)
    at iterateFiles.next (<anonymous>)
```

I have a somewhat unusual setup for legacy reasons:

- /home/project has two (relevant) folders: app, library
- app is our main package for a React app
- library is a separate package with some shared code, installed into app as a local dependency
- app/.eslintrc.js extends from react-app and react-app/jest
- library/.eslintrc.js extends from ../app/.eslintrc.js with some overrides

I get this error when running `npm run lint` from /home/project/app which runs `eslint src ../library/src` to run against both directories.

Interestingly, I don’t get this error when running from eslint-webpack-plugin during development (also configured to run against both directories).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what helped me

```
npm i eslint-plugin-jest -D
```